# Inconsistency in auto-reading the SMS by Digits

Tags: android, twitter-digits, google-fabric

Coming from https://twittercommunity.com/t/inconsistency-in-auto-reading-the-sms/84209.

Auto-reading the SMS is consistently inconsistent in my case. Most of the times, the SMS is not read for the first time but if I wait for the seconds to lapse and do a Resend Code, I have a higher chance for the SMS to be read automatically.

Enabled the debugging as suggested in the aforementioned thread but the debug logs didn't contain anything related to SMS reading part.

There aren't any special steps really, just the usual workflow -- submit the phone number, wait for OTP, Digits won't read it, wait for the timeout, do a Resend Code and Digits reads it fine.

I can reproduce this on my phone fairly consistently but the same exact app (with Digits) doesn't exhibit this problem on a different phone i.e., it reads the OTP just fine. I really wanted to understand why this is failing on my phone, at the least. I am concerned how many other phones may have this exact issue once we release the app to the public. Most users aren't likely to complain as they simply enter the OTP manually but the whole point of this is to automate this step and save those few secs.

Device - HTC One_M8
OS - Android 6.0
Carrier (if it matters): AT&T

Comment: _"Let me know if I should copy"_ ... yes, you should. StackOverflow tries to be as self-contained as possible. Visitors here (current and future) don't want to have to go skipping around the internet to know what you are talking about

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. So far, I remain unable to reproduce this, even when emulating the HTC One_M8 ; is this happening for other devices that you can test with?

Comment: @MikeBonnell, I tried on another phone and the SMS is being read consistently for the first time, but I want to understand why it doesn't work on my phone (and may be a bunch of other phones in future that share similar environment that triggers this issue) for the first time (most of the times) and works on the second attempt (again, most of the times).  Is it possible to add some verbose logging around the SMS reading part (the most verbose logging doesn't log anything around SMS reading part either for success/failure in logcat) so we can get a better sense of what is going on on my phone?

Comment: @MikeBonnell, I tried on another phone, this time, around 10 times and the results are random.  SMS got auto-read for 60% of the times and failed to read for the first time during other times.  Clicking `Resend Code` worked fine during the other 40% of the times.  So, yeah, the results are quite random and inconsistent.

Comment: There isn't additional logging other then debug mode that can be enabled at this point. Very odd that you're seeing the inconsistencies, will keep digging.

Comment: Thanks @MikeBonnell.  Do you have a per-incident paid support of some sort?  I would gladly have this issue resolved, assuming I can afford to pay for it.

Comment: We don't have a paid support model, but two things I thought of. 1) Are the internet connections and carriers the same across both devices?
2) How are you handling perms on Android 6.0 ? Are you handling runtime permissions ?

Comment: @MikeBonnell, the carriers are different for the two devices (AT&T and T-Mobile) and on different Internet connections.  The devices are running different OS versions too 6.0 and 5.1.  The app prompts for permissions during installation (namely, read phone status and identity and receive SMS).  Let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: @MikeBonnell, checking to see if the ball is dropped on this one.  If you need any further details, let me know.  I can reproduce this fairly consistently on more than one phone.  Thanks!

Comment: Yep, I dropped the ball. I tested with one of our senior Android engineers and we haven't been able to reproduce this. At this point, I'd recommend sharing a reproducable case on our Android repo: https://github.com/crashlytics/digits-android and code: https://github.com/crashlytics/digits-android/blob/7c3885b0af04ede3b4c5d3c264be67f92277495f/digits/src/main/java/com/digits/sdk/android/LoginCodeActivityDelegate.java#L203

Comment: I am getting the same problem, I've test the messages in some versions of Android, 4.2, 5.1, and 6. This messages happend most of all in 4 and 5 versions. I don't think the problem is for permissions, these versions, usually grant all the permissions from the Play Store installation.